# Reverse for 'user_page' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. I beleive my decorators are causing the issue

Tags: django, django-views, decorator

So my login view takes the user to the home.view but first checks user is logged in and then checks if the user is an admin or not through the decorator 'admin_only'. My user will prove to be false for this scenario (which is expected). The user is then redirected to the user_page view  to which first goes through the decorator allowed_users (which will be true) and then the user_page view.
My aim is to pass the primary key at login_user view to user_page view but the middle men decorators I believe are causing me problems.

views.py

```
@unauthenticated_user
def login_user (request):
    user = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        temp_username = request.POST.get('username')
        temp_password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=temp_username, password=temp_password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            context = {'user':user}
            print ('Primary key in login view = ', user.id)
            return redirect('home', context)
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username or Password is incorrect!")                   
    context = {'user':user }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@admin_only
def home(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'user':user}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def user_page(request,pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'user':user}
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
#url.py
path('user/<int:pk>/', views.user_page, name='user_page')
path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

decorators.py

```
def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(allow_users_view_function):
        def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

            if group in allowed_roles:
                user = request.user
                pk = user.id
                print('PK in allowed_users = ',pk )
                return allow_users_view_function(request,pk,*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("You are not authorised to view this page") 
        return wrapper_function
    return decorator
```

```
def admin_only(admin_view_function):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == 'customer':
            print('group = customer')
            user = kwargs.get('user')
            print ('Primary key in admin_only = ', user.id)
            
            pk = user.id
            print('PK in admin_only = ',pk )
            context={'pk':pk}
            return redirect('user_page', context)    
        
        if group == 'admin':
            print('group = admin')
            return admin_view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)      
    return wrapper_function
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'user_page' pk=user.id %}" method="POST"> # error is occuring at this line
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<!--Display error message for any failed login attempt-->
{% for message in messages %}
    <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
{% endfor %}

Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" >Sign Up</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you need to unpack your context in your redirect params... please change   `return redirect('user_page', context)`   to   `return redirect('user_page', **context)`  in `def user_page(request,pk):`'s body and see if that solves your problem. If this does not solve your problem, please attach your full error traceback to your question.